# Why do I have to use (flush) in this code?

Tags: clojure

It's my first contact with Clojure, so I tried to write simple script which provides translation based on wikipedia (any critics / comments are welcome)

The problem is: **when I remove (flush) from *translate*, script outputs nil instead of translated word.** Why is that? I am clearly missing something, but what? (println translations) gives same result that flush (at the beginning I tried with doseq / doall, but without results)

(Using Clojure 1.2 and testing in eclipse 3.7.2 with counterclockwise)

The code:

```
(ns wiki-translate
    (:require [clojure.contrib.http.agent :as h])
)

(defn get-url
    ([lg term] (str "http://" lg ".wikipedia.org/wiki/" term))
)

(defn fetch-url
    ([url] (h/string (h/http-agent url)))
)

(defn get-translations
    ([cnt]  (apply sorted-map (flatten (for  [s (re-seq #"(?i)interwiki-([^\"]+).*wiki\/([^\"]+)\".*/a>" cnt)] [(s 1) (s 2)])))))

(defn translate
    [term src-lg tgt-lg] (
        (def translations (get-translations (fetch-url (get-url src-lg term)))  )
        (flush)
        (if (contains?  translations tgt-lg) (get translations tgt-lg) "<NOT FOUND>")               
    )           
)

(println (translate "Shark" "en" "fr"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `translate` function has an extra level of parentheses, and `(flush)` makes it work by accident. Without `(flush)`, the code is

```
((def translations (get-translations (fetch-url (get-url src-lg term))))
 (if (contains?  translations tgt-lg) (get translations tgt-lg) "<NOT FOUND>"))
```

Clojure evaluates this form according to [its evaluation rules](http://clojure.org/evaluation) by evaluating the two sub-forms and calling the first as a function. With the sub-forms evaluated, the form becomes

```
(#'translations
 "Requin")
```

because the first form returns the Var being defined, and defines it in time for the second form to succeed in the look-up. When you call a Var as a function, [the call is delegated to the value of the Var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113387/explanation-about-symbols-and-vars-and-their-differences-in-clojure/9115958#9115958), which is a map, and since [map implements function call as look-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686375/why-does-def-vowel-set-aeiou-work/686807#686807), the effect is to look up "Requin" in the map. The map has no element with that key, so the value is nil.

With the `(flush)` added in between, the same process happens:

```
((def translations (get-translations (fetch-url (get-url src-lg term))))
 (flush)
 (if (contains?  translations tgt-lg) (get translations tgt-lg) "<NOT FOUND>"))
```

is first evaluated into

```
(#'translations
 nil
 "Requin")
```

and again the map that is the value of `#'translations` is called. This time the effect is to look up `nil`, with "Requin" as the default value returned in case `nil` is not found in the map.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `let` rather than `def` inside the translate function:

```
(defn translate
    [term src-lg tgt-lg] 
    (let [translations (get-translations (fetch-url (get-url src-lg term)))]
      (if (contains?  translations tgt-lg) (get translations tgt-lg) "<NOT FOUND>")))
```

let is used to create local binding for the forms in the let block. Using def creates a global binding (in current namespace). So basically after executing your exiting code you can use the var `transalations` outside of the function because it is being created using def at global scope.

I am not exactly sure what flush has to do with def to make it work. Probably someone with deep knowledge of how def works can shed some light on this and that would be a interesting thing to know for sure.

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly wrapping the function body in `do` makes it work with `def` without flush but that is not something you should do. Using `let` is the preferred way. `do` is used to perform a series of expression that have side effects so it seems that `def` is a kind of side effect expression and using `do` or `flush` makes it "actually" execute the side effect operation.